# How to load graphical login screen?

Tags: 11.10, gnome, gdm, lightdm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to load graphical display manager when booting?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/85307/how-to-load-graphical-display-manager-when-booting)

I have just upgrade to 11.10 from 10.04. I cannot see login screen on tty7. I can still login into tty 1-6. I have tried install gnome-shell from gnome3 ppa and gnome-panel but it doesn't help.

What should I do?

Comment: It was saying unrecognized service

Comment: when you said you upgraded from 10.04 to 11.10 - how did you do that?

Comment: @fossfreedom: I first run cdromupgrade from alternate CD of 11.04 and then again run cdromupgrade from alternate CD of 11.10

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following command in a terminal:

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install lightdm`

to ensure that Lightdm is properly installed.